# Reproject full swath data with VRT files

Tags: python, coordinate-system, gdal

I am attempting to follow the following link to reproject swath data to a grid. http://geoinformaticstutorial.blogspot.com/2014/06/reading-and-map-projecting-amsr-2-data.html

In this link it is suggested to implement .vrt files which link to other vrt files detailing the latitude and longitude arrays of interest which are stored in netcdf files.

My specific files I have created are as follows and are approximated for the purpose of this question:

lat_Copy.vrt

```
NETCDF:"C:\Path\to\latlon\netcdf\file\file.nc"://lat_array
```

lon_Copy.vrt

```
NETCDF:"C:\Path\to\latlon\netcdf\file\file.nc"://lon_array
```

data_Copy

```
"C:\Path\to\lat_Copy.vrt"
"C:\Path\to\lon_Copy.vrt"
NETCDF:"C:\Path\to\data\netcdf\file\data.nc"://data_array
```

And then I run gdal with the following command:

```
gdalwarp -geoloc -t_srs EPSG:4326 "C:\path\to\data_Copy.vrt" test01.tif
```

Unfortunately the following error occurs when running this command:

```
ERROR 4: `C:\path\to\data_Copy.vrt' not recognized as a supported file format.
```

I am not sure where I have gone wrong in the file format. I have attempted adding in the 1's and 0's after each line as suggested in the blog post but nothing has come of it and only the same error appears.

I do have alternate .vrt files for the lat lon datasets that I have made but still produce the same error as above but I will post them if requested.

EDIT: I was able to solve my conundrum by copying the file format at this link in the answer provided by fer.marino [Map project a raster having separate latitude and longitude raster bands](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/103116/map-project-a-raster-having-separate-latitude-and-longitude-raster-bands)

Comment: Maybe related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/198957/patch-processing-of-multiple-hdf5-files-using-python-and-gdal-gdalwarp and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81361/how-to-reproject-modis-swath-data-to-wgs84

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve my question I was able to follow this link [Map project a raster having separate latitude and longitude raster bands](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/103116/map-project-a-raster-having-separate-latitude-and-longitude-raster-bands) and manually build the vrt files.